# JavaScript index.js .babelrc error "Do not clone comments tha...<omitted>... } could not be cloned"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, babeljs

Update:
the error seems to be related to the .babelrc file I had:

```
{
    "presets": ["env", "react"],
    "plugins": ["transform-class-properties", "transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

When I remove this file, the error disappears.

Original Post:

I am using React with Parcel-bundler.
First, I had an issue which had to do with an incompatibility of my parcel version and @babel/preset-env (Invalid version: undefined).

I resolved by adding a resolutions tag to the package.json file to enforce usage of a previous version of Babel which does not require a version object.
This worked, but now I get the following error when I build the client

**npm run clean && parcel build client/src/index.html --out-dir client/dist**:

> .../client/src/index.js: function __clone() {
> var node2 = new Node();
> for (var key in this) {// Do not clone comments tha...omitted... } could not be cloned.

...

> at Object.serialize (v8.js:202:7)

I searched here and in google, but cannot find this error anywhere.

Any idea what that might be?

For reference, here some excerpts from package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "elliptic": "^6.4.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "hex-to-binary": "^1.0.1",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "npm-force-resolutions": "0.0.10",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.10.3",
    "pubnub": "^4.21.6",
    "react": "^16.6.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "redis": "^2.8.0",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.13.8"
  }   

and 

"devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.4"}
```

Answer (score 9):

Thank you.  I have been trying to solve this problem all weekend and simply removing the .babelrc, then replacing it after running 'parcel index.html', seems to have fixed it. Parcel 7+ claims to no longer need babel configuration, so setting it up in .babelrc might have confused the initial cloning process.

Answer (score 4):

I have been able to solve the same problem as follows:

First, replace your dependencies like this:

- "babel-preset-env" -> "@babel/preset-env"
- "babel-preset-react" -> "@babel/preset-react"
- "babel-core" -> "@babel/core"

In my case I have all of them as devDependencies, I don't know whether this matters or not. Then, however, also make sure your .babelrc looks something like this:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

After implementing those changes in my environment I did not receive the error anymore when running Parcel.